# React Firebase to do list app slow after adding function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I've been building a to-do list app with authentication and everything was working fine until I added the "function for searching database by UID and searchInput". The app allows users to add, edit, delete, and search tasks that are stored in Firebase. There are two collections, tasks and users, which are connected to each other by UID. Here is the code in ToDo.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, doc, addDoc, updateDoc, deleteDoc, Timestamp, query, orderBy, onSnapshot, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { BsFillPencilFill, BsFillTrashFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { IoMdAddCircle } from "react-icons/io";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth, db, logout } from "./utils/firebase";

export default function Todo() {

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

    //function for automatically retrieving items
    useEffect(() => {
        getCollectionById();
    }, [])

    //search database by UID
    function getCollectionById() {
        const q = query(collection(db, 'tasks'), where("uid", "==", user?.uid));
        onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            setTasks(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data()
            })))
        })
    }

    //function for getting the value of the main input
    function handleChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setName(e.target.value);
        console.log(name);
    }

    //function for getting the value of the search input
    function handleSearchChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSearchInput(e.target.value)
    }

    //function for searching database by UID and searchInput
    if (searchInput.length > 0) {
        const q = query(collection(db, 'tasks'), where("uid", "==", user?.uid), where("name", ">=", searchInput), where("name", "<=", searchInput + '\uf8ff'));
        onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            setTasks(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data()
            })))
        })
    } else {
        getCollectionById();
    }

    //function for adding items to firestore
    const handleAdd = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (name === "") {
            alert("Please enter some text");
            clearInput();
            return;
        }
        try {
            await addDoc(collection(db, 'tasks'), {
                name: name,
                completed: false,
                created: Timestamp.now(),
                uid: user?.uid,
            })
            clearInput();
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    //function for adding strikethrough to an item
    function handleClick(e) {
        if (e.detail === 2) {
            console.log("double click");
            e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('double-clicked');
        }
    }

    //function for updating an item
    const handleUpdate = async (taskName, id) => {
        let name = prompt("Please enter a new name", taskName);
        if (name === null) {
            return;
        }
        const taskDocRef = doc(db, 'tasks', id)
        try {
            await updateDoc(taskDocRef, {
                name: name,
            })
            clearInput();
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    //function for deleting an item
    const handleDelete = async (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        const taskDocRef = doc(db, 'tasks', id)
        try {
            await deleteDoc(taskDocRef)
            clearInput();
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    //function for clearing and focusing the input
    function clearInput() {
        let input = document.querySelector("input");
        input.value = '';
        input.focus();
        setName("");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>To Do List App</h1>
                    <p>Double click to mark an item off.</p>
                </div>
                <input
                    id="input"
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    autoFocus
                />
                <button
                    className="add-button"
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={handleAdd}
                >
                    <IoMdAddCircle />
                </button>
            </div>

            <ol>
                {tasks.map((task) => (
                    <li
                        class="task-list-items"
                        id={task.id}
                        key={task.id}
                        completed={task.data.completed}
                        onClick={handleClick}
                    >
                        {task.data.name}
                        <button
                            className="edit-button"
                            onClick={() => handleUpdate(task.data.name, task.id)}
                        >
                            <BsFillPencilFill />
                        </button>
                        <button
                            className="delete-button"
                            onClick={() => handleDelete(task.id)}
                        >
                            <BsFillTrashFill />
                        </button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ol>

            <div>
                <h5>Search for an item by name</h5>
                <input
                    id="search-bar"
                    type="text"
                    value={searchInput}
                    onChange={handleSearchChange}
                />
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Does your field "name" is a number? If not, why you use ">="?

Comment: User will have millions of tasks? That why you try to use query? It won't be faster if you search result from tasks? You are getting all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by filtering the tasks array instead of searching the database. Here is my updated code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, doc, addDoc, updateDoc, deleteDoc, Timestamp, query, orderBy, onSnapshot, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { BsFillPencilFill, BsFillTrashFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { IoMdAddCircle } from "react-icons/io";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth, db, logout } from "./utils/firebase";

export default function Todo() {

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

    //function for automatically retrieving items
    useEffect(() => {
        const q = query(collection(db, 'tasks'), where("uid", "==", user?.uid));
        onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            setTasks(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data()
            })))
        })
    }, [])

    //function for getting the value of the main input
    function handleChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setName(e.target.value);
        console.log(name);
    }

    //function for getting the value of the search input
    function handleSearchChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSearchInput(e.target.value)
    }

    //function for adding items to firestore
    const handleAdd = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (name === "") {
            alert("Please enter some text");
            clearInput();
            return;
        }
        try {
            await addDoc(collection(db, 'tasks'), {
                name: name,
                completed: false,
                created: Timestamp.now(),
                uid: user?.uid,
            })
            clearInput();
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    //function for adding strikethrough to an item
    function handleClick(e) {
        if (e.detail === 2) {
            console.log("double click");
            e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('double-clicked');
        }
    }

    //function for updating an item
    const handleUpdate = async (taskName, id) => {
        let name = prompt("Please enter a new name", taskName);
        if (name === null) {
            return;
        }
        const taskDocRef = doc(db, 'tasks', id)
        try {
            await updateDoc(taskDocRef, {
                name: name,
            })
            clearInput();
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    //function for deleting an item
    const handleDelete = async (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        const taskDocRef = doc(db, 'tasks', id)
        try {
            await deleteDoc(taskDocRef)
            clearInput();
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

    //function for clearing and focusing the input
    function clearInput() {
        let input = document.querySelector("input");
        input.value = '';
        input.focus();
        setName("");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>To Do List App</h1>
                    <p>Double click to mark an item off.</p>
                </div>
                <input
                    id="input"
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    autoFocus
                />
                <button
                    className="add-button"
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={handleAdd}
                >
                    <IoMdAddCircle />
                </button>
            </div>

            <ol>
                {tasks.filter(task => task.data.name.includes(searchInput)).map(task => (
                    <li
                        className="task-list-items"
                        id={task.id}
                        key={task.id}
                        completed={task.data.completed}
                        onClick={handleClick}
                    >
                        {task.data.name}
                        <button
                            className="edit-button"
                            onClick={() => handleUpdate(task.data.name, task.id)}
                        >
                            <BsFillPencilFill />
                        </button>
                        <button
                            className="delete-button"
                            onClick={() => handleDelete(task.id)}
                        >
                            <BsFillTrashFill />
                        </button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ol>

            <div>
                <h5>Search for an item by name</h5>
                <input
                    id="search-bar"
                    type="text"
                    value={searchInput}
                    onChange={handleSearchChange}
                />
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};
```